# Razor: Create Checkbox with Eventhandler

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

Usually, when I create checkboxes, I do it like this:

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.checkLangs.Count; i++)
                                                    {
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].Name)
                                                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].LanguageId)
                                                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].isChecked)
                                                                <label>@Model.checkLangs[i].Name</label>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    }
```

I bind this to a model, and when the submit button is clicked, I react to the changes that have been made.

Now however, I want a checkbox that is not bound to any model but instead, if this is checked, it checks or unchecks ALL my other checkboxes.

My though is:
add eventhandler -> alter model according to isChecked? -> do the rest via submit button.

But I couldnt find a tutorial on this.
How would you go on about this?

Thank you!

Comment: The functionality you're describing sounds like it would be entirely in JavaScript on the resulting HTML, not in server-side code.  You would indeed create an event handler for a checkbox input, but in that handler you wouldn't *alter the model*, you'd simply check/uncheck all the target checkboxes.

Comment: That sounds absolutley perfect. Can you give me a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following js:

```
<script>
        $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        })
</script>
```

result:

[image]

**Update:**

Try to add a class to the checkboxes:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].isChecked,,new{@class="myClass"})
```

And use the following js:

```
$('input.myClass:checkbox').change(function() {
            $('input.myClass:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        })
```

Comment: thank you! but i have other checkboxes in that page too, now those get unchecked as well. unfortunately, I am unfirmiliar with that sintax. how can I define the checkboxes that are going to be affected and the ones that are not?